# django jquery autocomplete not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am tryinng to build jquery autocomplete in django but it returns this response in the browser "The view rango.views.AutoCompleteView didn't return an HttpResponse object." Where am i going wrong ?

the search box

```
<form id = "aa"  class = "form-inline" method = "post" action="">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text"  name = "cat_name" class = "form-control" id = "cat" value = ""/>
    <input class ="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit"/>

</form>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
  $("#cat").autocomplete({          
  source: "/rango/autocomplete/",
  minLength:2,
  });
});
```

the view

```
class AutoCompleteView(FormView):
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    data = request.GET
    item = data.get("term")

    if item:
        cats = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains = item)
    else:
        cats = Category.objects.all()
        results = []

        for cat in cats:
            cat_json = {}
            cat_json['id'] = cat.id
            cat_json['label'] = cat.item
            cat_json['value'] = cat.item
            results.append(cat_json)
            data = json.dumps(results)
            mimetype = 'application/json'

            return HttpResponse(data,mimetype)
```

urls.py

```
  url(r'^autocomplete/$',AutoCompleteView.as_view())
```

Comment: Is it a typo or your `return` is inside your `for`?

Comment: your indentation looks messed up big time.. Starting from `results = []`

Comment: i think its a typo,i was following a tutorial.

Comment: thank you ,i fixed the typo,no error messages in the chrome browser but still doesn't bring suggestions in the search box.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention that your view return `HttpResponse` only if you don't have 'term' in `request.GET` or have entries in `Category` model. Try to rewrite your code with this indent:

```
class AutoCompleteView(FormView):
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    data = request.GET
    item = data.get("term")

    if item is not None:
        cats = Category.objects.filter(name__icontains = item)
    else:
        cats = Category.objects.all()

    results = []

    for cat in cats:
        cat_json = {}
        cat_json['id'] = cat.id
        cat_json['label'] = cat.item
        cat_json['value'] = cat.item
        results.append(cat_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
    mimetype = 'application/json'

    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

See how it different so you will return `HttpResponse` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're return a list so you need to use **json.dumps()** function for this and also your indention looks really bad, don't align the **return** inside your ***for loop***.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
```

Please follow @valentjedi's answer.